# Create multiple variations, possibly using animation frames?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to quickly create and save multiple variations of some banner ads. I've found I can do this pretty effectively using animation frames with each frame containing one variation of the banner. The problem is that when I go to save, I can only save it as a big animated gif with all the frames in one file.

Is there a way to tell photoshop to save frames as a series of separate image files instead of one big animated gif?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save it by using a script from `File>Scripts>Layer Comps to Files...`.

Just choose a destination and change a file type to JPEG in a dialog box that you get after activating the script.

Of course, before that you have to create Layer Comps. You can do it by changing visibility of layers (as you probably did for the animation) and then creating Layer Comp for each of the states of your document.